# The truth (definite article)

Tags: articles

Why wouldn't you say "tell truth", and it always comes with "the" truth?

You ask someone just to tell truth generally, not something specific. Simply be honest is the main point. Why still need "the"?

Comment: Because ideally there is only one "truth" in any given situation.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an answer beyond "because *truth* is a count noun in English" and "you can only *tell* a count noun".

Comment: Think about the difference between _the truth_ and _truth._ Good question @JoeKim +1

Answer (score 1):

It is a <strike>binary</strike> ternary choice:

(x)  relevant truth    ( ) non-truth  ( ) irrelevant truth

[Radio-buttons, not checkboxes]

When making a choice, we use "the":

> I can offer you an apple, an orange, or a pear.
>   --I'll have **the** pear, thanks.

**The** refers to the choice-in-context, the selected item of a set of options.

Come on, tell me *the* truth (not the non-truth).

+1 to @user3169

Comment: Shouldn't the choices be (x) THE Truth and () non-truth (fallacy)?  A truth = a fact that is true, such as, "The moon is grey and dusty,"  The truth = a truth, as opposed to a fallacy.

Comment: "The truth = a truth" In "Tell the truth", *the* truth is not only *a* truth; it must be a *relevant* truth.  "Tell me the truth, where were you last night?" -- The moon is dusty.  That reply, about the moon, though a truth, is not *the* truth. So we need to edit the radio button :) It's ternary, not binary.

Answer (score 0):

No, because it is not always easy to tell truth from fiction.  (← See what I did there?  You wouldn't say "the fiction", would you?)

Comment: Very clever!  I would only point out that this usage of *tell*, in its sense as "distinguish", is slightly different from *tell* meaning "relate".

Comment: @stangdon Clever aye, but with expansion it might benefit many more subsequent questioners... hint hint...

Comment: @200_success, thank you but you are talking to another your culture person. In my culture it is no problem to say it. So I don't understand your distingushion and according to all the rules about "the", I don't what it is about.