# Why "the" should be used before 'truth'

Tags: exam-questions

Please identify and explain error in the following sentence

*After knowing truth , (1)/they took the right decision (2) / in the matter (3)/No error (4)*.

Also ,
Is it correct to use 'ing' form of 'know' here?

Comment: I'm confused. Is your question something about using "the," like your title says, or is it something about "knowing"? What do all the numbers mean?

Comment: It is about both of them. Numbers are used just to indicate parts of the sentence and we have to identify which  part has error

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/102365/

Comment: *the truth...?*

Comment: There are a number of errors in the sentence -- in fact, I'd go so far as to say all three sections are wrong.  It's kind of useless to pick apart a sentence that's not idiomatic, as it won't help you learn English.

Comment: Andrew, it is a single sentence only. In the exercise it was numbered just to answer which part out of (1) , (2) and (3) has error. Consider it as  a single sentence only

Comment: @SanatDubey What Andrew is saying is that all the parts are wrong. I'd reword this as _After **learning the** truth, they **made** the right decision **on** the matter_. The "in" vs. "on" isn't crucial, though.

Comment: @joiedevivre Please throw some light on correctness of usage of 'knowing' here and what difference it will create in meaning, if it is there.

Comment: You wouldn't talk about "after knowing" something, unless somebody used to know something but for some reason no longer knows it. And even then, it would be an unusual way to phrase it. If you instead say, "after learning," it means ever since they _acquired_ the knowledge (and that they still have it).

Answer (score 1):

As you are talking about a specific matter of truth, you should use the definite article "the" before the noun truth.  Further, the right phrase is to decide on something, not in something.  So the phrase should be "on the matter".  The complete sentence is as follows:

After knowing the truth, they took the right decision on the matter.

As for the use of the present participle knowing, you can use it after after to express that one action was after another action.  You can also use the phrase "having known" as follows, but it's more emphatic:

Having known the truth, they took the right decision on the matter.

Comment: +1 for all but the final sentence, with **having known**.  I don't find "having known" idiomatic in this context.  *having known* usually means "having experienced"   *Having known hunger as a child, she always kept her pantry well stocked.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo,  I respect your comments.