# Usage of "the" before "truth"

Tags: definite-article

Is it advisable to use "the" in the following sentence?

Crowdsourcing has been shown to be effective in deciphering **the** truth on social media.

I've [read](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/150769/152925) that "the" should be used before truth when we are talking about a specific matter of truth. So it seems like we should **not** use it in the above sentence. But I wanted to double-check it because a native speaker has reviewed the above text and has not raised a red flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence is correct with "the".

You're right that when we say "the truth", we mean the truth value of a specific matter. This means that in the phrase, "the truth on social media", we somehow do mean the truth of a specific matter. In this case, we mean whatever specific matter people are talking about in that specific place in social media. It will be a different matter in each case, but we are talking about specific truths, rather than the general concept of "truth", so it's correct.

Answer (score 4):

The use of the article is optional.

Without **the**, the sense is of truth as a general concept rather than any particular truth or truths, as though it there was a key to perceive truth directly.

**The truth** is slightly more specific, as though there were a particular truth or truths to be discovered as opposed to falsehoods, errors and conspiracy theories that litter social media.

Political commentators and preachers are more like to speak of **the truth**.

The choice depends on the context and what you want to say.

Comment: If you don't use "the" in that that sentence, then my mind will automatically capitalize the T in "truth" as I read it. Not because that's necessarily correct English (although I have seen exactly this kind of capitalization used), but because the implications of omitting the "the" makes the word "truth" signify something grander or deeper than merely whether a given statement is correct.