# buy the others / buy different ones

Tags: phrase-meaning

Do these sentences have the same meaning? Are they interchangeable?

> Don’t buy these headphones, **buy the others**.
>
> Don’t buy these headphones, **buy different ones**.

Comment: Do you think they mean the same thing? Have you tried to find the answer yourself?

Comment: @Ronald Sole, I have read these versions under another post. As I understand it, "the others" mean the rest of all. But there were written these versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why many abstract nouns get an indefinite article while it's taught that abstract nouns shouldn't get it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152041/why-many-abstract-nouns-get-an-indefinite-article-while-its-taught-that-abstrac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **others** refers to headphones that are already specified (by the definite article). So the people involved are already aware of the others in question. Person A is advising person B to buy the other headphones that they are considering.

**Different ones** merely means ones different to these. There is no reference to which ones might be different or how they might be different. Person A is not advising person B on which alternatives are preferable. In effect, the statement is saying **don't buy these ones; buy other ones**. (Note the absence of the definite article.)

So they don't mean the same thing; and they are not interchangeable.